# Django cannot use Sum with SQLite and time fields?

Tags: django, sqlite

I have a model with a time field, and I need to sum the time fields in all instances.

This is what I've tried:

```
total_hours = Day.objects.filter(date__year=current_year, date__month=current_month).aggregate(Sum('total_work_hours'))
print(total_hours)
```

and I get this error:

`You cannot use Sum, Avg, StdDev, and Variance aggregations on date/time fields in sqlite3 since date/time is saved as text.`

Is there a way around this? I'd like to stick with SQLite for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here's what I ended up doing. I added a map to convert the time objects to hours.

```
times = Day.objects.filter(date__year=current_year, date__month=current_month).values_list('total_work_hours', flat=True)
hours = map(lambda time: time.hour + (time.minute / 60.0), times)
total_hours = sum(hours)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without changing databases, you will have to do this in Python. You can do it rather cheaply by using `values_list` to just pull the `total_work_hours` for each day, and sum them.

```
hours = Day.objects.filter(
    date__year=current_year,
    date__month=current_month
).values_list('total_work_hours', flat=True)

total_hours = sum(hours)
print(total_hours)
```

Comment: That looks so good, but doesn't work unfortunately:

`unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.time'`

Comment: Ah, I assumed that `total_work_hours` was an integer. It is a time field?

Comment: Yep it's a time field. I just needed to add a map at the end of the first line, to extract the hour and minute values from the time object, and result in a list of floats/ints that can be summed. I'll post the full solution tonight